# Kafka Producer error in cluster with SASL_SSL/OAUTHBEARER

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, kafka-producer-api

I am tryin to create a Kafka producer in Java. I am using below configuration. My cluster is RBAC enabled with port 9094 using OAUTHBEARER. I am able to produce using console producer using same configuration shown below. But am getting an error running the Java producer.

```
bootstrap.servers= sp-sbox-broker-0.streawsnprd.mass.com:9094
schema.registry.url= https://sp-sbox-schema-registry-rest-proxy-0.streawsnprd.mass.com:8081
security.protocol=SASL_SSL
sasl.mechanism=OAUTHBEARER
ssl.truststore.location=/datapower/truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=trustpass
sasl.login.callback.handler.class=io.confluent.kafka.clients.plugins.auth.token.TokenUserLoginCallbackHandler
sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.oauthbearer.OAuthBearerLoginModule required username=\"svcprd\" password=\"****\" metadataServerUrls="https://sp-sbox-broker-0.streawsnprd.mass.com:8090";
```

The error is shown below. The user has been granted SystemAdmin role on Kafka cluster as well as Schema registry cluster. Can someone please explain what is causing the error ?

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka producer
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:432)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:298)
    at com.massmutual.AvroProducer.main(AvroProducer.java:27)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while fetching activeMetadataServerURLs.
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SaslChannelBuilder.configure(SaslChannelBuilder.java:158)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.ChannelBuilders.create(ChannelBuilders.java:146)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.ChannelBuilders.clientChannelBuilder(ChannelBuilders.java:67)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.createChannelBuilder(ClientUtils.java:99)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.newSender(KafkaProducer.java:450)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:421)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while fetching activeMetadataServerURLs.
    at io.confluent.security.auth.client.rest.RestClient.scheduleMetadataServiceUrlRefresh(RestClient.java:151)
    at io.confluent.security.auth.client.rest.RestClient.<init>(RestClient.java:129)
    at io.confluent.security.auth.client.rest.RestClient.<init>(RestClient.java:95)
    at io.confluent.kafka.clients.plugins.auth.token.TokenUserLoginCallbackHandler.configure(TokenUserLoginCallbackHandler.java:67)
    at io.confluent.kafka.clients.plugins.auth.token.AbstractTokenLoginCallbackHandler.configure(AbstractTokenLoginCallbackHandler.java:86)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.LoginManager.<init>(LoginManager.java:60)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.LoginManager.acquireLoginManager(LoginManager.java:105)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SaslChannelBuilder.configure(SaslChannelBuilder.java:147)
```

Answer (score 2):

This issue arises due to access issue . In my project , Confluent Kafka was hosted in a AWS cloud and I needed to be added to an Active Directory Group . All the team members who are part of  Active Directory Group don't face the same issue